# MySQL assigning an empty value

Tags: mysql, null

I have a foreign key in my 'useroptions' table that points to countryId in the table country:

```
countryId VARCHAR(2)
FOREIGN KEY(countryId) REFERENCES country(code)
```

I want the user to be able to update this field to some sort of 'empty' value in case the user does not want to submit his country (and this should be the default value as well).

How would one approach this? I've tried to use 'NULL', but a HTML form can't submit the value 'NULL' apparently (atleast not what I know of?)

Comment: Introduce the country with name "UNKNOWN/NOT GIVEN" (or ""). Then there is no need to change your database, because the foreign key still works...

Comment: I will do this for now - thank you. I'm still wondering though, what if I had an age that I wanted to update from 5 to NULL through an HTML form (because the user don't want to show his age)? Here I can't have a field with an empty string, since age is the datatype of integer.

Comment: Don't save age in DB. It will be invalid next year. Save instead year_of_birth or birtday

Comment: About `null` values you can solve this in your update/insert query like `countryId = IF(countryId='', null, countryId)`, so when webform send empty code null will be inserted

Comment: HTML forms can't submit numbers or dates either, but that doesn't prevent you from having `INT` or `DATETIME` columns. You do the appropriate mapping and conversions in your application code. In this case, the obvious choice would be an empty option, as in `<option value="">Unknown / Prefer not to say</option>`.

Comment: Is this a mysql question or is this more like a html / php (or whatever language you use in the backend) one? In mysql the answer is to set the fk to null, without any ', so not 'null'. This should work as long as the fk column is nullable. From php you have to do the same: execute an sql statement seting the fk to null. You have to map the html form value that says not assigned to null.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev There is special function NULLIF(). So `IF(countryId='', null, countryId)` may be replaced with simple `NULLIF(countryId, '')`.